# User Controlls to Main Form C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am using Windows Forms .NET C# for this project
I am making a school project for a cafe ordering system. And the coffee aspect is a simple custom controller that allows users to pick out a size of the coffee, how many sugars and creams they want. My issue is that I then have to take that user control inputs and store them in the main form list and inside a ListBox as a display of an order.

Does anyone know how to store user control inputs into a main form List<>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to create a class to store info about order, let's call it class "Order". Each order will be represented by instance of this class (you pass your control's values as parameters to the constructor). You can store orders in the List<Order>.

To add it to the ListBox, you must override ToString() method:
`public override string ToString(){ return "onfo to show" }`
This method will show info about order from your class in the way you like.

P.s. for more specific help provide sample code of what you have tried since now.